# Rattling noise inside driver side air vent

Tags: noise, heater, vibration, vents

2014 Renault. I bought it almost new and didn't have this issue.

When the heat is Off I can hear a rattling/vibration noise that comes from the inside of the driver side's air vent. It doesn't happen when heat is On.

I have no idea of what the cause of this is. It only appears when I'm driving, and it intensifies on rugged asphalt and streets that are on bad conditions. I don't hear this noise from the other vents.

Is there any way to know what this issue could be?, should I fix it by myself or take the car to the workshop?

Comment: Can you only hear it from that vent? It's possible some kind of debris fell into the vent that is light enough to be shoved against a wall when the heat is on. Have you tried looking down the vent with a flashlight?

Comment: I can only hear the noise from that vent. That's a good idea

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can try looking down the vent with a flashlight to see if the object is visible. On the off chance the object is made of ferrous material, you can get a telescoping magnetic grabber tool for fairly cheap at a hardware store and try sticking it down the vent. There are also small claw style grabbers if the magnet doesn't work. Otherwise, you will likely need to remove some trim to access the inside of the vent.

If you can't get to it from above, there is a chance the debris is lodged in or near the cabin air filter housing, which would make it much easier to get to. I'm not sure your specific model, but I'm sure you can find procedures to access (and replace since you're in there, they cost ~12 USD) the filter by entering 'cabin air filter renault blahblah turbo' into your favorite search engine.

Good luck!